# Spring Boot Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

Simple Spring Boot POST request not working and returns:
"Request method 'POST' not supported" error message.

The code itself looks fine to me, but I'm not so sure about the pom.xml.
If the problem relies in the pom.xml, then this case is hopeless since I don't even know what all those dependencies do nor why there are duplicates.

Here is my controller class:

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepository;


@GetMapping("/")
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("students", studentRepository.findAll());
    return "index";
}


@PostMapping("/")
public String add(@RequestParam String name) {
    Student student = new Student(name);
    this.studentRepository.save(student);
    return "redirect:/";
}
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>List all students </p>

    <p>Add a Student</p>

 <form th:action="@{/}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<p>Students</p>

<p th:each="student : ${students}">
    <span th:text="${student.name}">student name</span>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fluentlenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluentlenium-junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fluentlenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluentlenium-assertj</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    </dependency>  

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
</project>
```

The code is supposed to add a student to studentRepository and redirect back to index.html and display the added student instantly.

Error Message from soapUI:

```
"timestamp": "2019-05-24T09:02:36.088+0000",
"status": 405,
"error": "Method Not Allowed",
"message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
"trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: 
"path": "/"
```

Full trace:

```
> "trace":
> "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: 
> Request method 'POST' not supported\r\n\tat 
> org.springframework.web.servlet.support.WebContentGenerator.checkRequest(WebContentGenerator.java:380)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:163)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)\r\n\tat
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)\r\n\tat
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\r\n\tat
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\r\n"
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8083
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./database;create=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

**Tutorial which is working fine:**

Controller class

```
@Controller
public class ItemDatabaseController {

@Autowired
private ItemRepository itemRepository;

@GetMapping("/")
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("items", this.itemRepository.findAll());
    return "index";
}

@PostMapping("/")
public String add(@RequestParam String name) {
    this.itemRepository.save(new Item(name));
    return "redirect:/";
}

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Item Database</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Item Database</h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Items</th>
        </tr>

        <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
            <td th:text="${item.name}">Item name</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <h2>Add an item</h2>

    <form th:action="@{/}" method="POST">
        <span>Name:</span>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Add!"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fluentlenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluentlenium-junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fluentlenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluentlenium-assertj</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

These two are virtually the same, except this tutorial was downloaded and my own project was created in Eclipse as a Spring Boot: Spring Starter Project. Which is an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: What are you getting back if you try to hit the endpoint with Postman? So you know if the problem is the Controller or your html.

Comment: added the error message to the end of the post

Comment: @PostMapping(path = "/", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json") public void add(@RequestBody String name) { ...}, could resolve

Comment: your controller seems fine no Issue with a controller, just check from UI are you calling an expected method, the issue seems like the method you are calling have difrrent mapping on controller

Comment: none of these worked

Comment: we need to eliminate some things, can you please post you application.properties file so that there is no weird context path set.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I have now added the application.properties at the end of the post

Comment: i suspect your post from soapUI is doing something fishy. Can you please log from soapUI what path you are calling, and what the body of your request looks like.

Second i concur with others you need to annotate the class with either RestController or Controller and ResponseBody at the top.

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/08/difference-between-restcontroller-and-controller-annotations-spring-mvc-rest.html

Comment: I added the tutorial from which I created my project. It has no RestController nor ResponseBody, and still works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, if you are performing the request from a form, the annotation `@RequestParam` may be wrong. That is used to get a parameter from the url (`?name=myname`). You may want to try `@RequestBody`.

Comment: I have a template tutorial in which the @RequestParam is working with html form

Answer (score 0):

Use @RestController instead of @Controller Annotation or

simply use

```
@PostMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
```

Comment: If you are using '@requestparam' then you should include the params in url .If you want to use the form input use '@requestbody'

Comment: RequestParam does work with html form. Spring Boot can parse the attributes introduced in the form with RequestParam.

Comment: It depends on your spring boot version. lower version does not support this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest few tweaks in existing code. Please see if it works.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepository;


@GetMapping("/")
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("students", studentRepository.findAll());
    return "index";
}


@PostMapping(path = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public String add(@RequestBody String name) {
    Student student = new Student(name);
    this.studentRepository.save(student);
    return "redirect:/";
}
}
```

Hope it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this `Request method 'POST' not supported` error when my html was in `static` folder and the error went away when I moved the html to `templates`. I think basically Thymeleaf does not manipulate html in `static` folder.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33590294)